# Need help in debugging AsyncTask with layout view

Tags: android, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I am using an Asynctask in the splash screen to add database items into database. 
The insert process went well but the splash view just won't show up.

I am posting my code below, any advice would be appreciated. thx

splash.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/splash">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Splash.java

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

     private ChannelDB mDB;
     private TextView loading;
     private String channelS_TABLE;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);  
        new SetDB().execute();

    }

    private class SetDB extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                if (tabIsExist(channelS_TABLE) !=true){
                    **some database insert**  
                }else{
                    synchronized(this){
                        Log.i("Splash", "the table is there");
                        wait(3000);}
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClassName("com.appkon.hdtvs",
                                   "com.appkon.hdtvs.HDtvs");
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                }   
               }catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.i("Splash", "setDB exception");
                        Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setClassName("com.appkon.hdtvs",
                                       "com.appkon.hdtvs.HDtvs");
                        finish();
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
            return null;
        }


        protected void onPreExecute(String load) {
            synchronized (this) { try {
                wait(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String finish) {
             Intent i = new Intent();
             i.setClassName("com.appkon.hdtvs",
                            "com.appkon.hdtvs.HDtvs");
             finish();
             startActivity(i);
        }
    }


        public boolean tabIsExist(String tableName){
            boolean result = false;
            if(tableName == null){
                    return false;
            }
            Cursor cursor= ChannelDB.check();
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
            try {
                    if(cursor.moveToNext()){
                            int count = cursor.getInt(0);
                            if(count>0){
                                    result = true;
                            }
                    }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(this.toString(),"error:"+e.toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,HDtvs.class);  
                startActivity(intent);  
                this.finish(); 
            }                
            return result;
        }


    }
```

I changed the xml

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/splash">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/bg"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/splash"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

still not working and the database insert is not workong too.

Comment: Why are you stalling the UI thread by waiting 2 seconds in `onPreExecute`?

Comment: Where is your view? You have to defined ImageView under RelativeLayout. Otherwise it will show you blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

`RelativeLayout` is a container. Its background will only show when you have some elements / views inside it. I am not sure about it though. But you can try this - remove the image from the background of the `RelativeLayout`, and create an `ImageView` inside the `RelativeLayout` and set the `ImageView's` source image as your desired image. You should get the desired result.

Comment: Are you sure that Background for RelativeLayout will not work?

Comment: @PareshMayani No I am not. I have editted my answer to indicate that.

Comment: @Aki well,the problem's still there and I noticed I got a setDB exception

Comment: Then fix the setDb exception first.